# Python2: TypeError while checking dictionary value

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, salt-stack

I have the following Python code to iterate over a nested dictionary and grab a value from the second child:

```
ret = some_dict
for item, val in ret.items():
    for item2, val2 in val.items():
        print val2['result']
```

When I test this in IPython or the interactive Python interpreter, the code works fine, and prints the value of val2['result'] for each item in the dictionary. However, when I use this block of code in a Python program I get the following error when trying to print val2['result']:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

If I print json.dumps(val2, indent=2), I can see that the dictionary is formed correctly. Attempting to use dict() to cast val2 to a dictionary in the script also fails with the following error:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong at this point, since the code works in the interactive interpreter. I am using Python 2.7.6, and the use case is iterating over a dictionary returned by the Saltstack Python client.

Comment: I'm guessing that `some_dict` is not what you think it is. Your code would work if it was `{'outer_key': {'inner_key': {'result': "foo"}}}` but seems like your dictionary is just  `{'outer_key': {'inner_key': "foo"}}`.

Comment: Put up the some_dict.

Comment: Just insert a "print val2" before the line producing the error to see if you have the expected content.

Comment: I'll put up a scrubbed example of what is returned by our saltmaster.

Comment: No, put up `some_dict`

Comment: I'll put up some_dict, but what I posted a few minutes ago is the specific nested dict that i'm having trouble accessing. This will take a few minutes since I have to scrub the json for sensitive information

Comment: I've updated the question with the value of some_dict

Comment: Ahhhh in pasting this i think i found the issue, i was expecting this to be a nested dict i'm iterating over but it looks like it's not nested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe the message: it is telling you that `val2` is a string when you think it is a dict. This is almost certainly due to your JSON data not being structured as you think it is.

Comment: You were right all along, I was expecting to be iterating over a nested dict when in truth I was not

Comment: Half the battle in learning to program is learning to be extremely literal. Unfortunately if you let this carry over into the rest of your life you run the risk of being thought a dullard.